# Selecting a div which is nested below another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is a simple thing to do but can't get my head around what I'm doing wrong. I have a h2 tag which will run a function on click, this will then locate a div with the class 'homeSlide' and then run the slideToggle method. However I can't seem to get the content to slide without making the two divs below with the same class name also slide.

Here is my HTML:

```
<h2>Header</h2>

<div id="home_newproducts_list">
   <div class="category-products">
      <ul class="products-grid">
         <li>Hold fetured products so will be excluded from the slideToggle</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="homeSlide">
         <!-- Content that needs to be displayed on slide -->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#home_newproducts_list ul.products-grid").not(":first").wrapAll('<div class="homeSlide">');         
            jQuery(".home-spot h2").click(function(){
               jQuery(this).next('.homeSlide').slideToggle(1000);

            });

          });
```

I hope i've explained it in enough detial.

So all I want to be able to do is run the slideToggle method on the homeSlide div, but only on the next one after the h2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery(".home-spot h2")
```

assuming you are selecting the `<h2>Header</h2>` element here

try with `next()` and `find()`.

```
  jQuery(this).next().find('.homeSlide').slideToggle(1000);
```

`next()` gets  the immediately following sibling which is div#home_newproducts_list in your case

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thank you! I thought I was close, I didn't release next was the immediate following sibling. I thought you could specifcy the next class or ID.

Comment: @JoshDavies... yes we were real close..anyways welcome.. glad it helped... cheers!!! happy coding.. :)